# Concurrent Modification Exception in map overlays

Tags: android, exception, android-maps

```
Hi I have a map application where I need to show all the markers fetched from database onto map it is don on pressing a button. It shows perfectly for the pressing once but if i press the button twice then it gives ConcurrentModificationException. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my asynctask class for loading the markers onto map from database.

    class LoadMarkers extends AsyncTask<Void , Void , Void>
        {

            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() 
            {

                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(DemoAccidentReport.this , "Loading Markers" , "Please wait..." , true , false);
                Log.d("after progress dialog onPreExecute()------->" , "onPreExecute()");
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
            {

                Log.d("after progress dialog doInBackground()------->" , "doInBackground()");

                try
                {
                    db = openOrCreateDatabase("LocationFetch.db", MODE_PRIVATE , null);

                    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user" , null);

                    drawableOne = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.location_blue);

                    final List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                    //helloItemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawableOne , DemoAccidentReport.this);           
                    //helloItemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawableOne);

                    popUpitemizedOverlay = new MyPopupItemizedOverlay(drawableOne, mapView);
                    Log.d("after progress dialog doInBackground() One------->" , "doInBackground()");

                    //itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem>(drawableOne , mapView);

                    Log.d("after progress dialog doInBackground()Two------->" , "doInBackground()");

                    while(cursor.moveToNext())
                    {

                        int dataID = cursor.getColumnIndex("id");

                        String dataString = cursor.getString(0);
                        Log.d("ID DATA FROM DATABASE---->" , dataString);

                        String dataNAME = cursor.getString(1).toString().trim();
                        Log.d("NAME DATA FROM DATABASE---->", dataNAME);

                        String dataDESCRIPTION = cursor.getString(6);
                        Log.d("DESCRIPTION--------->" , dataDESCRIPTION);

                        String dataLAT = cursor.getString(2).toString().trim();
                        //Log.d("LAT DATA FROM DATABASE----->" , dataLAT);

                        double latitude = Double.parseDouble(dataLAT)*1000000;
                        Log.d("LATDOUBLE DATA FROM DATABASE----->" , latitude+"");

                        String dataLON = cursor.getString(3).toString().trim();
                        //Log.d("LONDOUBLE DATA FROM DATABASE----->" , dataLON);

                        double longitude = Double.parseDouble(dataLON)*1000000;
                        Log.d("LONDOUBLE DATA FROM DATABASE----->" , longitude+"");


                        //Image at column 4

                        //byte[] picture = cursor.getBlob(4);

                        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(cursor.getBlob(4));

                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                        //showLatLon(latitude , longitude , dataNAME);
                        //ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
                        //OverlayItem[] markerItem = {new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude) , ""+dataNAME , ""+dataString)};
                        //OverlayItem markerItem = new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint((int)(latitude *1E6), (int)(longitude *1E6)) , ""+dataNAME , ""+dataString);\
                        //helloItemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
                        //mapView.getOverlays().add(helloItemizedOverlay);
                        //mapOverlays.add(helloItemizedOverlay);

                        /*CustomOverlayItem overlayItem = new CustomOverlayItem(new GeoPoint((int)(latitude *1E6), (int)(longitude *1E6)), ""+dataLAT , ""+dataLON , R.drawable.icon);
                        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
                        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);*/



                        //-------WORKING POPUP ONLY TITLE AND DESCRIPTION------//

                        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint((int)latitude , (int)longitude) , ""+dataNAME , ""+dataDESCRIPTION /*null*/ );

                        popUpitemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);

                        mapView.getOverlays().add(popUpitemizedOverlay);

                        mapOverlays.add(popUpitemizedOverlay);


                    }

                }catch(SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();                
                }finally
                {
                    cursor.close();
                }

                db.close();

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }


        }
```

here is the exception from logcat which throws me exception of Concurrent ModificationException where on pressing twice the button even it is not shows the first marker only shows from the second marker:

```
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:576)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.draw(OverlayBundle.java:41)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:530)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6880)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6986)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1683)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1940)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1527)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1264)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-10 14:05:14.898: E/AndroidRuntime(8991):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: stacktrace from logcat ?

Comment: give us stacktrace please

Comment: edited please check and give me any solution.

Comment: Hi please help if anyone as I am stuck here. As i have edited my question along with logcat.